# Calculating data lengths and writing offset values to binary stream

Tags: c#

I'm writing data using `BinaryWriter` to a gzip-compressed file stream. I want to include offset values in the header, so that on read, I can seek and read only specific parts rather than the whole file.

However, I'm not finding a clear documentation on how to *set* these values.

Here's an example of the writer I have currently:

```
using (var writer = new BinaryWriter(stream)) {
  foreach (IPersistedObject obj in objectsToWrite) {
     writer.Write(target.Key);
     writer.Write(target.SchemaVersion);
     // writer a bunch of object-specific data
  }
}
```

But to write an offset in the file header, I need to:

1. Encode all of these to binary first
2. Check their length
3. Write their offset/length to the file header
4. Then write the actual data

I also assume that the compression will muck all of that up. Is this how it's going to work or am I missing some other technique?

I'm also not clear how to properly check the binary length of the data. Based on existing docs I need to use Convert.ToString first and then check its length.

Comment: Here we go again.  First do you care how long it takes to pack binary, or just the read times?  You first need requirements.  Previous posting you were concern only about unpack times.  Also you were only talking about binary, now you are considering packing to strings which takes time to pack and unpack.  gzip will take care of the packing so you don't need to do another level of packing.  With binary data all you have to do is precede each object with a byte count so you can unpack each object.  Adding pointer(s) to object make access quicker but additional take time to pack.

Comment: I was asking a different question (same topic, just seeking advice on the general approach) with a previous post, so I'm not clear what you're answering here. I've always been writing primitives to binary files using the BinaryWriter. "How do I calculate the offsets" is what I'm trying to understand. The only reason the gzip was added, months ago, was to compress the resulting file to keep file sizes down. I can remove it if it's going to impede my offset work. I just want to stop using a unique file for every unique component.

Comment: Nothing wrong with gzip, just don't pack data before using gzip.  The offsets are a sum of previous offset.  So you have assuming length is a long 8 bytes : Block 1 = (length_1 object_1, length_2, object_2, length_3 object_3).  So block 2 offset is 8 + length_1 + 8 + length_2 + 8 + length_3.

Comment: Right, which means I need to calculate the binary size of every piece of data before I can write the lengths, correct? I need the offsets written in the file header, so I'm trying to understand the best way to determine their length before they've actually been written. Also, I don't understand what you mean by "pack". I'm writing the data to the BinaryWriter, I'm not doing any "packing" outside of gzip.

Comment: Pack could mean zip, compress or encode.  The size need to be written before each write of the current writes.  So the size would be sizeof(target.Key) and sizeof(target.SchemaVersion).

Comment: your comment brings us back to my question - how do I calculate the sizes of the data? `sizeof` requires a type, but I need to calculate the exact length a string, int, float, bool, etc will be as I write the data.

Comment: I suppose for strings I can do `str.Length * sizeof(char)`, and `sizeof(short)` for other primitives.

Comment: If you have an array the Length property.

Comment: I really don't feel like you understand what I'm asking.

Comment: String you cannot us sizeof(char) because a character because some characters are one byte and others two bytes.  There is a private property that is not readable that indications if a character is one or two bytes.  So if you are putting a string into a binary file you should use Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(string) and Encoding.UTF8.GetString(byte[]).  Bytes are always the same size. Short are two bytes.  You can use Marshal.SizeOf(object) to get sizes of objects.